# How to use lining figures in siunitx and fontspec?

Tags: fontspec, siunitx, oldstylenums

I'm using XeTeX and [`fontspec`](http://ctan.org/pkg/fontspec), and I have selected old-style figures for my body text. Now I use the [`siunitx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/siunitx) package, and have set it up to use text fonts instead of math fonts. For the `siunitx` values I want to use lining figures instead of old-style figures. How do I do this?

I have tried this, but it does not work:

```
\setromanfont[Numbers=OldStyle]{Arno Pro}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{mode = text}
\sisetup{inter-unit-separator =\cdot}
\sisetup{detect-all}
<snip>
{\fontspec[Numbers={Lining}]{Arno Pro}\SI{10}{\kilo\volt\per\centi\metre}}
```

Furthermore, `siunitx` uses the math font comma instead of the text font comma when using

```
 \sisetup{output-decimal-marker ={,}}
```

Comment: Is there a convenient free font offering old style numbers? I don't have Arno Pro to test this.

Comment: Calibri offers them, Cambria too.

Comment: The libertine font

Comment: @Ruud: Calibri and Cambria aren't free.

Comment: @Joseph: Herbert has already mentioned Linux Libertine, others are Antykwa Poltawskiego, Antykwa Torunska, Asana Math, Computer Modern, Cyklop, GFS Artemisia, GFS Baskerville, GFS Bodoni, GFS Didot, GFS Neohellenic, Iwona, Kurier, Latin Modern, Linux Biolinum, Neo Euler, TeX Gyre Adventor, TeX Gyre Bonum, TeX Gyre Chorus, TeX Gyre Cursor, TeX Gyre Heros, TeX Gyre Pagella, TeX Gyre Schola, TeX Gyre Termes, Vollkorn, XITS. TeX Live alone contains dozens of those.

Comment: @Philipp. Thanks for that. BTW, TeX Live does not really 'include' any of these: they are not installed in the system font directory and so are not available to XeTeX. (I was actually thinking 'free' as in freely available: installed on Windows, Mac and Linux by default. However, 'free' as in 'you can download them' will also do here.)

Comment: @Philipp. Of course, I should therefore have said 'readily available'.

Comment: @Ruud. Ideally, stick to 'one issue per question' as it makes it easier for people searching to home-in on what they want. I've covered both parts of the question in my answer, but you might consider posting the comma part as an additional question.

Comment: I should have opened a new question for the comma, but it seemed like a minor issue.

@Phillip: you can get them free of charge by installing Powerpoint Viewer (though this only works on Windows).

Comment: @JosephWright `\usepackage[osf]{mathpazo}` should give you text figures on any texlive system.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Font detection in `siunitx` uses the document defaults unless you provide something else. So in your example your getting `\rmfamily`. The key is to define a font command which will select what you want.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec,siunitx}
\setromanfont[Numbers=OldStyle]{Linux Libertine O}
\newfontfamily\liningroman[Numbers={Lining}]{Linux Libertine O}
\sisetup{mode = text,number-text-rm = \liningroman}
\begin{document}
1234567890
\SI{123456789}{\kilo\volt\per\centi\metre}
\end{document}
```

I see that there is a second part to the question, asking about the `output-decimal-marker` option. As detailed in the manual, this is a math mode option. If you want to force this to be in text mode you need to use `\text`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec,siunitx}
\setromanfont[Numbers=OldStyle]{Linux Libertine O}
\newfontfamily\liningroman[Numbers={Lining}]{Linux Libertine O}
\sisetup{mode = text,number-text-rm = \liningroman,
  output-decimal-marker=\text{,}}
\begin{document}
1234567890
\SI{123.456789}{\kilo\volt\per\centi\metre}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You shouldn't use `\newcommand` and `\fontspec` to do this. You should use `fontspec`'s `\newfontfamily` command: `\newfontfamily\liningroman[Numbers={Lining}]{Linux Libertine O}`

Comment: @Alan. Altered - I can't say I use the `fontspec` beyond loading it, so I've never had occasion to set up a new font family before.

Comment: The reason is that when you put `\fontspec` to select a font into a command like that, every time you use the command, it has to parse the font features over again; the `\newfontfamily` kind of encapsulates the features and is therefore much more efficient.

Comment: This solution works perfectly, thank you very much!

Comment: Why is `number-text-rm` not mentioned in the `siunitx` documentation? I couldn’t find it by searching.

Comment: @lblb 'Every one of the font options can be given independently for units and number, with the prefixes `unit-` and `number-`, respectively.': there are a lot of options this applies to, and listing them all in the docs seems like overkill.