# How to use siunitx with mathdesign and Adobe Garamond fonts?

Tags: siunitx, mathdesign

I have seen [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8979/how-to-use-lining-figures-in-siunitx-and-fontspec), but in making an MWE I discovered that this happens without `fontspec` loaded at all. I would expect that `siunitx`'s mode detection would cause output to match the numerals in either text or math mode in the rest of the document.

This works as I'd expect with two fonts including oldstyle numerals (`cfr-lm` and `mathpazo`): the numerals used in `\num{560}` correspond to those used in `560`, and the same for `\(\num{560}\)` and `\(560\)`.

But using `adobe-garamond` with `mathdesign`, I get oldstyle numerals with `\(\num{560}\)` while getting uppercase numerals with `\(560\)`. The behavior is the same if I use `$ $` or `\( \)` to delimit math mode. I tried to find a free font that also has this issue, but was unsuccessful; so I apologize in advance for that inconvenience.

How can I use `siunitx` with `\usepackage[adobe-garamond]{mathdesign}` and have `siunitx`'s mode detection function properly?

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{cfr-lm} % this works as expected
%\usepackage[osf]{mathpazo} % this works as expected
%\usepackage{mathpazo} % this also works as expected
\usepackage[adobe-garamond]{mathdesign} % this doesn't work as expected (siunitx typesets oldstyle figures)
\usepackage{siunitx}
%\sisetup{detect-all} % tried this; it has no effect

\begin{document}
Here, a test of numerals in text mode: 560

And numerals in mathematics mode: \(560\)

And numerals in \textsf{siunitx} macros (text): \num{560}

And numerals in \textsf{siunitx} macros (math): \(\num{560}\)

% for Joseph's comment:
With mathnormal: $\mathnormal{560}$

With mathrm: $\mathrm{560}$
\end{document}
```

**Output**

[image]

*I realize that the sans serif fonts are bitmapped in my MWE; I just didn't load anything else for the purpose of keeping the MWE minimal.

Comment: I don' have the font here, but my suspicion is `\mathrm` _versus_ `\mathnormal`. Could you try a 'reference rendering' using them?

Comment: @JosephWright you mean something like comparing `$\mathrm{560}$` to `$\mathnormal{560}$`, correct?

Comment: Yes, exactly: the standard settings in `siunitx` use `\mathrm`, but that may not always be the best choice.

Comment: @JosephWright I edited this in... now I'm even more confused... why would math mode digits be slanted/italicized?

Comment: @JosephWright I just found that `mdpgd.sty` doesn't set `\mathnormal`, so a default or fall-back is likely to be used. I don't know much of the TeXnical details behind math alphabets, but it seems to me that this might be relevant?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The mechanisms used by `siunitx` assume more-or-less 'well-behaved' setting of LaTeX font commands. In particular, in math mode the package uses `\mathrm` to typeset output as standard. If that fails, using `\mathnormal` is the usual fall back but here that does not appear to apply. I would therefore go to the second fall back of using `\ensuremath`:

```
\sisetup{number-math-rm = \ensuremath}
```

which will essentially force 'normal math mode' on the output. This of course will mess up formatting if you have any letters inside a number, but as that is unlikely you should be OK.

Comment: It works here for me, and I don't think I'll have any issues with letters in numbers. If I do, they'll be few enough in number to handle case-by-case I think.