# Using OpenType superior figures with siunitx

Tags: fontspec, siunitx, superscripts, opentype

I want to use the specifically designed OpenType superior figures in my document. Doing this with `fontspec` is easy enough, but I couldn’t get `siunitx` to make the change as well and the package provides no suitable setting for the font of superscript numbers to hook into. How can this be done?

The solution should still allow `siunitx` to change the font used depending on the environment, as shown in my example.

I’ve looked at Joseph's answer here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/8992/75284 (changing `number-text-rm`), but that solution is limited to one font family, the one chosen in the `\newfontfamily` command, whereas I need more flexibility. Also, the OpenType superior figures don’t need any repositioning, they have the right size and position by default.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}

% choose an OpenType font with superior figures
\setmainfont{Cambria}

% sans-serif font with OpenType superior figures
\setsansfont{Segoe UI}

\usepackage[detect-all]{siunitx}

% custom superscript with the OpenType feature
\newcommand\xsup[1]{{\addfontfeature{VerticalPosition=Superior}#1}}

\begin{document}
2\xsup{21} \si{\meter\squared} 2\textsuperscript{21}

\sffamily % additional test for sans-serif
2\xsup{21} \si{\meter\squared} 2\textsuperscript{21}
\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: The get the superior figures with \textsuperscript, you can use the `realscripts` package. Be aware that there is not But for siunitx you will imho have to make a feature request (https://github.com/josephwright/siunitx/issues). Be aware that only cambria seems to have a sensible superior minus (which you can enter e.g. as \xsup{^^^^2212 21}) and check also for times and other possible symbols you could need.

Answer (score 1):

It becomes clear that enabling the use of OpenType superior figures in `siunitx` would require adding this as a new feature. In the meantime, I’ve tried to simulate the superior figures by using a slightly bolder font variant. My example uses *Times LT Pro* and *Neue Haas Unica Pro*, both commercial fonts. Use fonts with semibold/medium cuts of your own collection to compile the example.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont[
    UprightFont = {*-Roman},
    UprightFeatures={SizeFeatures={{Size={-11},Font=*-Semibold},{Size={-15},Font=*-Roman}}} % comment this line to see effect
]{TimesLTPro} % choose font with semibold/medium

\setsansfont[
    UprightFont = {*-Regular},
    UprightFeatures={SizeFeatures={{Size={-11},Font=*-Medium},{Size={-15},Font=*-Regular}}}, % comment this line to see difference
]{NeueHaasUnicaPro} % choose font with semibold/medium

\usepackage[detect-family, mode=text]{siunitx}

\begin{document}
          m\textsuperscript{−2} \si{\per\meter\squared}

\sffamily m\textsuperscript{−2} \si{\per\meter\squared}
\end{document}
```

And a GIF (with manual alignment) to show the difference:
[image: example]

From my experience, opical sizes would be designed to be slightly wider than a semibold cut for regular size. For me, though, this trick is good enough. If the font offers semibold-semiextended or similar, this might look even better and closer to the opical size variant.

Comment: I've since come to realise that the concept of OpenType superior figures as a whole is too limited and a font should simply provide suitable opical sizes instead. That way not only numbers will look better in exponents and the like, but also all other glyphs.